# Find txt files, create an empty file for each of them, then delete the original file

Tags: java, file, find, delete-file

Can anyone tell me how it is possible in java to search and find specific file extension like txt, then delete it, and then create another file with the deleted full name?

I need this java script to find and delete really big txt files in a directory, but for information purposes, I need to keep track of the deleted file by creating an empty file with the deleted file's name.

For example:
under folder x, it finds the file name.txt with 300MB or whatever size. it deletes it. then it creates an empty file named:  name.txt with 1KB or so instead of that deleted file.

Any ideas?

Comment: Do you really need Java to do that for you?

Comment: Using Java for this is akin to killing a bug with a sledgehammer; why not just use the shell?

Comment: I agree with devnull and fge that Java is a little overkill for a task like this, but if you insist, have a look at the [File API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/package-summary.html)

Comment: thanks for all your responses, well I thought about java because I thought I would need something like java for that deletion stuff. Of course I would be more than happy if one gives me a clue how I can do it in bash shell. however I will try these java pieces as well and will post the entire code once done. thanks again

Answer (score 1):

If you're not using Java7, here's a solution. Otherwise take a look @Heuster's comment.

```
    File dir = new File("/directoryToFile");
    File [] files = dir.listFiles(new FilenameFilter() {
        @Override
        public boolean accept(File dir, String name) {
            return name.equals("fileName.txt");
        }
    });
    if(files != null && files.length > 0){
        File f = new File(files[0].getAbsolutePath());
        files[0].delete();
        f.createNewFile();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
    for (File file : new File(dir).listFiles()) {
        // delete
        file.delete();
        // create a new file with the same name and len = 1024
        RandomAccessFile f = new RandomAccessFile(file, "rw");
        f.setLength(1024);
        f.close();
    }
```